# How to use Datatable (https://datatables.net) with Laravel5.4 and npm

Tags: laravel-5, npm, datatables

I've Googled and seems nothing in particular that answers my question. I saw this though https://datatables.yajrabox.com/ but since Datatable is front-end component and my requirement is that Datatable will only be populated from Ajax request when a button is clicked, I want to include the npm package of the Datatable to the build output of the npm run dev so that i can use the $('#table').Datatable() elsewhere. Can anyone help me please? I'm not so expert with front-end development.

I already tried adding

```
var $       = require( 'jquery' );
var dt      = require( 'datatables.net' )();
var buttons = require( 'datatables.net-buttons' )();
```

or with arguments as the their manual says

```
var $       = require( 'jquery' );
var dt      = require( 'datatables.net' )( window, $ );
var buttons = require( 'datatables.net-buttons' )( window, $ );
```

I'm only getting this error

```
$(...).DataTable is not a function
```

I even tried downgrading datatables.net version to 1.10.9 as what [Downgrade datatables.net version](https://github.com/hmrc/assets-frontend/pull/456) said, but still no luck .

Thanks,

Comment: Please make sure there is no double core jquery added, laravel app.js includes core jquery.